# Basic Authentication + SSL - what do do with the credentials once they're on the server?

Tags: security, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Say a user submits their credentials using basic authentication.  I have a custom message handler that retrieves the credentials from the header:

```
protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
                                                                               System.Threading.CancellationToken
                                                                                   cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                // Request Processing
                var headers = request.Headers;

                if (headers.Authorization != null && SCHEME.Equals(headers.Authorization.Scheme))
                {
                    Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
                    string credentials = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(headers.Authorization.Parameter));
                    string[] parts = credentials.Split(':');
                    string userId = parts[0].Trim();
                    string password = parts[1].Trim();
                    // TODO: Authentication of userId and Pasword against credentials store here
```

I'm wondering - when I actually authenticate the userId and password here, I'm tempted to compare the plaintext from this method to plaintext stored in the database, but I know this is insecure.  Should I be hashing both the plaintext from the header and credentials stored in the database to compare indirectly?

If so, it seems like the credentials are in plaintext in the messagehandler, before they get hashed.  Does this present any kind of security vulnerability, or is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is data in motion and data at rest. Hashing is typically for data at rest, specifically password kind of things, where the user will be submitting the un-hashed form for you to hash and compare against the authority. If you are worried about clear password stored, hash it and store. Retrieve the password in clear text from the header, hash it and compare against the one in the database. If your concern is sending password over the wire, you should not be using basic authn.

Answer (score 0):

SSL covers you on having the credentials in plaintext as they are passed over the wire.

Passwords should definitely be hashed and salted in the database, and never saved anywhere in plaintext.

Having the passwords in a string variable on the server is really only a problem if you have someone memory-scraping your server. And if that happens, you have bigger problems. If you're concerned about minimizing that window of availability, you can take the password from the header and put it into a byte array instead of a string, so you can clear the byte array as soon as you are finished with it. However, the value is already stored in a string in `headers.Authorization.Parameter`, so that may not gain you much.